# Unable to enter safe mode. Gets stuck at progress bar (100%) while trying to log in

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safe-mode

Macbook Pro Retina 13", late 2013.

Unable to enter safe mode (via holding shift key). Result as in title.
Hangs after me waiting for mutliple minutes.

What troubleshooting can I do?

Need safe mode to do other troubleshootings.

Edit1: note, that the progress bar at first moves but very very slowly, compared to non-safe-mode logging-in.
Maybe I should wait overnight or something?
Is there a way to show any debug messages while this is running?

Also asked on Apple forum: https://discussions.apple.com/message/31699416#31699416

Comment: What's the longest you've waited for Safe Mode to finish booting? Generally Safe Mode will take longer to boot up. With your hardware if it's still _frozen_ after 10 or so minutes after the progress bar has stopped, I'd say you've waited long enough. Also, do you have either (or both) FileVault enabled or a Firmware password set? Finally, are you using the built-in keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

The "solution" was just to wait much much longer (longer than any other boot you have seen), patiently and not assume it was broken :).

Comment: For anyone else who faces his - I left it for about 30 mins before it finally booted into safe mode.